# Where'd my Solaris task bar go?

Tags: solaris, login, task-manager

I've got a user here that has a curious problem.  Upon login, he gets a "Unable to open panel because the panel is already open" error message.  His session does not display a task bar, but otherwise works just fine!  No errors (other than the usual that everybody gets) in the .dt logs.  Double ctl-alt-backspace doesn't help.  No one else on the machine has the problem.  Seems like something that a reboot probably wouldn't fix (and a reboot would be highly disruptive as it's a busy machine with many users).  Prefer not to have to delete/recreate his account.  Any ideas on how I might fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I attempted the gnome cleanup methods as suggested, with no improvement in the situation.  I'm not sure on what the root cause is, but I was able to help the user by replacing that thin client.  Makes no sense, since there's no state on the box and I'm not aware of any "per-user" state on the system.  None of our other users that use that station had any problems logging into it, and the user with the problem found that he could login anywhere else just fine.  Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about tracking this would be to rename/move the ~/.dt .gnome .gnome2 etc. files. They get recreated when the user logs in if they are missing.

Comment: Solaris includes a `gnome-cleanup` command to remove all the gnome dotfiles scattered around the user's home directory and /var/tmp.

Comment: Unfortunately, cleaning up gnome did not fix this particular problem.